# How to search a files in multiple folders that returns no duplicate in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find all the files in the multiple folders but the only thing is that the files existed in some folders

```
E:\sample\cd.dll
E:\sample1\sample\cd.dll
```

If I am using the

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse
```

it returns Two FileSystemInfo of cd.dll.
The result should be only one FileName of cd.dll
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ChiltItem -recurse | Select-Object -Unique
```

Note that -Unique is case-sensitive so you may want to use the Sort-Object cmdlet:

```
Get-ChiltItem -recurse | Sort-Object -Unique
```

You can also eliminates duplicates with the `Get-Unique` cmdlet but it requires the objects to be sorted first for the cmdlet to work properly

Comment: Consider using `Sort-Object -Property FullName -Unique`. From my experience, when taking uniques from many objects, it can go very slowly. Taking only FullName seems to improves performance.

Comment: Good point, it would be better to base the uniqueness on a property.